# raise AttributeError: Response content isn't text Scarpy proxy pool. How to solve?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Raises **AttributeError: Response content isn't text**. I am using scrapy_proxy_pool and scrapy_user_agents. I am trying to find each and every link of target website.

```
import scrapy

class LinksSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'links'
    allowed_domains = ['www.chotosite.com','chotosite.com']

    extracted_links = []

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = 'https://www.chotosite.com'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=start_urls, callback=self.extract_link)

    def extract_link(self, response):
        # eleminating images url from links
        str_response_content_type = str(response.headers.get('content-type'))
        if str_response_content_type == "b'text/html; charset=UTF-8'" :
            
            links = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()

            for link in links:
                if "chotosite" in link and link not in self.extracted_links:
                    self.extracted_links.append(link)
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.extract_link)

                    yield {
                        "links": link
                    }
```

Here is my settings.py file

```
BOT_NAME = 'chotosite'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['chotosite.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'chotosite.spiders'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
PROXY_POOL_ENABLED = True


DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.ProxyPoolMiddleware': 610,
    'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
}

AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
```

Here is the big console output in pastebin https://pastebin.com/tRbfvxdN

And here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1362, in returnValue
    raise _DefGen_Return(val)
twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return: <200 https://www.chotosite.com>
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 53, in process_response
    response = yield method(request=request, response=response, spider=spider)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy_proxy_pool/middlewares.py", line 287, in process_response
    ban = is_ban(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy_proxy_pool/policy.py", line 15, in response_is_ban
    if self.BANNED_PATTERN.search(response.text):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scrapy/http/response/__init__.py", line 93, in text
    raise AttributeError("Response content isn't text")
AttributeError: Response content isn't text
```

And this is what installed on my system

```
Scrapy       : 1.7.3
lxml         : 4.5.0.0
libxml2      : 2.9.10
cssselect    : 1.1.0
parsel       : 1.5.2
w3lib        : 1.21.0
Twisted      : 18.9.0
Python       : 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) - [GCC 9.3.0]
pyOpenSSL    : 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020)
cryptography : 2.8
Platform     : Linux-5.4.0-53-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked package [source code (origin of error)](https://github.com/rejoiceinhope/scrapy-proxy-pool/blob/master/scrapy_proxy_pool/policy.py) and
[related issue on `scrapy-proxy-pool` github repository](https://github.com/rejoiceinhope/scrapy-proxy-pool/issues/6)

The problem is that default BanDetectionPolicy on current version of scrapy-proxy-pool checking for phrases "Captive Portal" and "SESSION EXPIRED" - of course it will cause error for non text responses.

Option 1 - downgrade scrapy-proxy-pool to version 0.17 
<strike>Is not option - remove `BanDetectionMiddleware` from `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES`setting.</strike>
Option 2: add custom `BanDetectionPolicy` and replace error code lines:

```py
# myproject/policy.py
from scrapy_proxy_pool.policy import BanDetectionPolicy

class BanDetectionPolicyNotText(BanDetectionPolicy):

    def response_is_ban(self, request, response):
        # if self.BANNED_PATTERN.search(response.text): <-this line caused error
        #    return True

        if response.status not in self.NOT_BAN_STATUSES:
            return True
        if response.status == 200 and not len(response.body):
            return True
```

add specific setting to use this ban detection policy to your settings.py:

```py
# settings.py
PROXY_POOL_BAN_POLICY = 'myproject.policy.BanDetectionPolicyNotText'
```

Comment: Option 1 worked for me. I am curious, for option 2, do I need to copy the above code into the new file **Policy.py** in my project folder? Please, guide!